# Migrating from struts 1 to struts 2 for Javascript

Tags: javascript, struts2

Migrating from struts 1 to struts 2 Javascript problem.

Struts 1 project has a logonForm.
Struts 1 project Javascript as following:

```
function doLogin() {
    document.logonForm.userId.value = document.logonForm.userId.value
        .toUpperCase();
    document.logonForm.btnLogin.value = '<bean:message key="button.login" />';
    disableButtons(document.forms[0]);
    document.logonForm.submit();
}
```

Migrating the Javascript code from Struts 1 to Struts 2.
Struts2 has no form bean. (NO more logonForm)
The “document.logonForm.userId.value” failed

> “ERROR
>   [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/].[default]]
>   (http--0.0.0.0-8080-8) Servlet.service() for servlet default threw
>   exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Parameters processing
>   failed.

How can I fix the Javascript error (NO more logonForm) for Struts 2?

Comment: You need to refactor the whole thing, not only change some javascript line. There are nice answers here on SO explaining the guidelines to perform this migration... start searching

Comment: Hi Thomas,     Thank you for the answer. I will search it.

Comment: Thomas edited, I commented, nobody answered :)